# How do I make a Sub or Function in a Module ComVisible?

Tags: vb.net, com

I've tried this:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
Module MyModule
  <ComVisible(True)> _
  Public Sub HelloWorld()
    Msgbox("Hello World")
  End Sub
End Module
```

... but the Sub isn't visible!

I know to use ComVisible(True), ComClass(...) on classes and specify guids, but I can't seem to figure out what to do for Modules.

Comment: That's just not possible, only a Class or Interface can be visible.   The compiler ought to generate an error message for it but forgets to do so.  Perhaps not entirely by accident, the VB language specification never once mentions [ComVisible].  A VB.NET module does not have an instance associated with it, all its members are implicitly *Shared*.  A concept that does not exist in COM.  COM uses a hyper-pure interface-based programming paradigm and an interface always requires an instance.

Comment: @HansPassant, if this was an answer, I would accept it.  Thanks for confirming that "modules" can't be made ComVisible.  I wish the compiler would error and tell me that I can't make members of a module ComVisible, when I add <ComVisible(True)>.